# How do you solve $\displaystyle \frac{n}{n+1}$ questions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fractions

$1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5... + 99/100.$

I've checked a lot of websites, but I still quite can't understand how do you do it.   I think you're supposed to convert everything into a common denominator?

Please help, I really appreciate your answers.

Edit:
After much thinking and discussions with my teachers and my friends, I came up with this equation:

1/2 + 2/3 + 3/4 + 4/5 +... + 99/100
= (1- 1/2)+(1- 1/3)+(1- 1/4)+...+(1- 1/100)
= 99-(1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +... + 1/100)
= 99-(1/(2+3+4+...+100)
= 99-(1/5049)
= 98+(5048/5049)

However, when I try to find the sum, I end up with 94.8126, like what Claude did. However, without using a calculator, how can I get the right answer as a fraction (mixed number)? There must be something wrong with my equation and I can't find it. Please help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104334/discussion-on-question-by-unidentifiedx-how-do-you-solve-n-n1-questions).

Comment: Your latest edit seems to assume that
$$
1/a_1 + 1/a_2 + \cdots + 1/a_n = 1/(a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_n),
$$
which is not true.

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

This sum will not have a convenient closed form.  This is because it is essentially a [Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) for which closed forms are not known.

Specifically, your sum is $$\sum_{n=1}^{99}\frac n{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^{99}\left(1-\frac 1{n+1}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{99}1-\sum_{n=1}^{99}\frac 1{n+1}=99-\sum_{n=1}^{99} \frac 1{n+1}$$ and the final summation is a Harmonic number.  (well, technically, it is $H_{100}-1$, but it is essentially a Harmonic number).

Answer (score 2):

Interesting could be the generalization
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac n{n+1}=p+1-H_{p+1}$$ Now, if $p$ is large, using the asymptotics of harmonic numbers will give
$$S_p=p+(1-\gamma) -\log \left({p}\right)-\frac{3}{2 p}+\frac{13}{12
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ Computed exactly
$$S_{99}=\frac{264414864639329557497913717698145082779489}{2788815009188499086581352357412492142272}=            94.8126225$$ while the above truncated expansion would give
$$S_{99}\sim \frac{11759431}{117612}-\gamma -\log (99)=94.8126235$$